# javascript to post to url and

Tags: php, html, tracking

I am writing a javascript which will post hostname of the site to a php page and get back response from it, but I don't know how to assign the hostname to `adrs` in url and not sure that code is correct or not.And this needs to done across server

javascript:

```
function ursl()
{
$.ajax({
url: 'http://example.com/en/member/track.php?adrs=',
success: function (response)
if (response)=='yes';
{
alert("yes");   

}
});
```

}
track.php

```
$url=$_GET['adrs'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM website_ad where site='$url'";
$res=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0)
{
    echo"no";
}
else
{
    echo"yes";
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: i know..but now i need it urgently...so plz help me to solve it

Comment: Then you need to learn it urgently.  I'm afraid the code you've posted is beyond fixing. Spend a few minutes googling the correct way to declare functions and create objects.

Comment: [This link](https://www.google.com/search?q=hostname+javascript) might actually help you. Use the tool more often before asking.

Comment: @user2345654, you've edited your code to incorporate some of the suggestions from the answers, but you are still making the same basic mistakes.  Try pasting your code into JSHint.com or JSLint.com, which will catch any synctactical mistakes.

Comment: hey ..i forgot to mention one thing that i want to make request across domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax function should be written thusly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/en/member/track.php?adrs=' + window.location.hostname,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response === 'yes') {
            $.getScript('http://example.com/en/pop.js', function () {
                // do anything that relies on this new script loading
            });
        }
    }
});
```

`window.location.hostname` will give you the host name. You are passing it to the ajax url by concatenating it.  Alternatively, as katana314 points out, you could pass the data in a separate parameter.  Your ajax call would then look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/en/member/track.php?adrs=',
    data: {adrs: window.location.hostname},
    success: function (response) {
        if (response === 'yes') {
            $.getScript('http://example.com/en/pop.js', function () {
                // do anything that relies on this new script loading
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what you intend `response` to be, but this code assumes it is a string and will match true if the string is 'yes'. If `response` is meant to be something else, you need to set your test accordingly.

`$.getScript()` will load your external script, but since it's asynchronous you'll have to put any code that is dependent on that in the callback.

Comment: thnx for your script i will try it

Comment: BTW, @user2345654, you've completely re-edited the code in your question. Someone might wonder why I am using `$.getScript()`, not realizing that you were initially trying to load a script by placing a script tag inside the conditional.

Comment: hey..i forgot to mention that i need it done cross-domain..i found that we can do it by json. can we?

Answer (score 1):

In this type of GET request, the variable simply comes after the equals sign in the URL. The most basic way is to write this:

```
url: 'http://example.com/en/member/track.php?adrs=' + valueToAdd,
```

Alternatively, JQuery has a more intuitive way of including it.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/en/member/track.php',
  data: { adrs: valueToAdd }
  // the rest of the parameters as you had them.
```

Also note that you can't put a script tag inside a script. You will need some other way to run the Javascript function mentioned; for instance, wrap its contents in a function, load that function first (with a script tag earlier in the HTML), and then call it on success.

And for the final puzzle piece, you can retrieve the current host with `window.location.host`

Comment: I would suggest using `window.location.hostname`, as `window.location.host` would also send a port number if there is one.

Comment: I'm surprised the fastest way to check wouldn't be just to try it. Most Javascript programming involves lots of trying and adjusting code. As far as I can tell, the problem you asked about should be solved; as others mentioned, you have a pretty serious SQL injection problem, and I can only hope you soon show concern for that...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change this line to look like so:

```
url: 'http://example.com/en/member/track.php?adrs='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)
```

The full `success` function should look like so:

```
success: function (response){
    if (response==="yes"){
        //do your thing here
    }
}
```

That should solve it...

Comment: no, you have some syntax errors in the code but i feel it's something you'll easily identify and fix